# UIView shadow displaying incorrectly

Tags: swift, uiview

I've run into this problem before, and usually been able to fix it by placing the code in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`. This works in every other view controller I have and I just can't find a solution.

I have a `UIView` and I'm adding a shadow to it like this:

```
func setUpUI() {
        for tile in roundedTiles {
            tile.layer.cornerRadius = t.frame.height/2

            tile.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            tile.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
            tile.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15
            tile.layer.addSpread(spread: -10)

            tile.layer.borderColor = GlobalConstants.Colors.lightGray.cgColor
            tile.layer.borderWidth = 1
        }

    }
```

I then call it here:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        setUpUI()
    }
```

However, this is what it looks like:

[image]

This is what it should look like, taken from another view controller where it's displaying correctly (and I have written the code there exactly the same):

[image]

After looking at other StackOverflow questions I've tried moving it to `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, `viewDidLoad()`, and adding `tile.layoutIfNeeded()`. Nothing is working. Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Is `layer.addSpread` a custom/extension function?

Comment: @Alexander Custom, though the issue is there even if I remove it

Comment: Are those views drawn in a .xib or storyboard?

Comment: @summerfinn3 storyboard

Comment: Is there any chance the wrong view has clipToBound set differently from the correct view?

Comment: Do not put this in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`, because this may be called multiple times during the lifecycle of the view. It seems like you have some cumulative changes, and each time the method is called, these changes start adding up. Also, this is inefficient in the sense that you don't need to reset the shadow properties each time; the layer remembers them just fine.

Comment: @summerfinn3 They're the same, `clipsToBounds` is `false` in both

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend subclassing UIView for your tiles and add the shadow and rounded corners in the init method, rather than adding it via the parent view controller.

The trick to getting rounded corners with a shadow is adding the shadow to the view itself, and then adding a subview for the rounded corners, which you can maskToBounds without affecting the parent.

So:

```
class roundedTile: UIView {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height/2

        // Add shadow to parent view
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 0.0)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0

        // Create subview for rounded corners
        let subView = UIView()
        subView.frame.size = self.frame.size

        subView.layer.cornerRadius = frame.height/2
        subView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        subView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        subView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        self.addSubview(subView)
    }
}
```

Season to taste the shadow offset/radius/opacity.

Comment: This actually works for the shadow! But, now I have an issue with corners and shadows around it! :D https://imgur.com/a/AQv0TqB

Comment: Updated my solution to involved a separate shadow layer. Corners and shadows don't play well together.

Comment: It did work for the shadow and the rounded corners but it filled it black! https://imgur.com/a/I5tUNF4 Wish rounded corners + shadows were simpler

Comment: Did you grab the latest from here? I tested it and it works. Does not fill black.

Comment: You have to set the background color of the subview to the color you want

Comment: The update got rid of the black color issue but now it looks as it did in the original question. Ahh

Comment: You need to adjust this line: 
`self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 0.0)`

Comment: Probably something like `self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)`